# Wordpress - Get current language on functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code added on my theme's `functions.php` file, in order to translate some *rebel* strings I was unable to translate by the ordinary way / plugins:

```
function wc_billing_field_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

switch ( $translated_text ) {

case 'Billing Address' :
    $translated_text = __( 'Detalles de facturación', 'woocommerce' );
    break;

case 'Shipping Address' :
    $translated_text = __( 'Dirección de envío', 'woocommerce' );
    break;          
}
return $translated_text;
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_billing_field_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Now I have installed WPML and I need this code to run only when the languaje is Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE contain current language https://wpml.org/documentation/support/wpml-coding-api/

But, if you already using WPML — why you don't get rid of this code at all and translate all string inside WPML admin?

Comment: Very grateful. I have also get in touch with WPML support to solve this, as those string just do not appear on the plugin's string translation.